# Panel scroll reset interfering with DataGridView usage

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've created a datagridview with a datagridviewcombobox in the end column. The datagridview is on a panel with AutoScroll set to TRUE. The combobox column is the only editable column. 
My problem is that after scrolling down, if i then click onto a row the panel scroll goes right back to the top so i have to scroll all the way back down again. Then only if i click in exactly the same row will i be able to make a selection change in the combobox otherwise the same jump back to the top occurs. This is extremely annoying and adds much time to usage as well as making it much harder to make the change where needed. I've tried to catch various datagridview events (RowEnter, CellLeave, RowValidated) and set the panel VerticalScroll.Value at that point but nothing seems to work and that jump back to the top always occurs. Everything else seems to work fine and i'm able to update data based on the combobox changes.
Any advise would be really great.
Thanks in advance.
Younis

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Could you post the minimum code required to duplicate the problem so we know where to start and can see what is going wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi hosch250, Many thanks for your response. I've actually managed to resolve the issue now after a good night's sleep!

Comment: I captured the VerticalScroll.Value with the datagridview CellMouseEnter event and then on a RowEnter event assigned this value to the panel's VerticalScroll.Value. So far it seems to be working OK although the scroll bar itself moves around a bit erratically! This isn't a problem though as the actual rows don't move allowing the user to enter a change with no jumping around.